# MIDI File playback library for iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, midi, coremidi

Is anyone aware of a library that can load a standard MIDI File and send the output to a MIDI interface? I've seen a number of libraries that play MIDI Files into an internal synthesizer, but none that will output to the MIDI interface.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with `MusicSequence` from AudioToolbox.framework.

Create a MusicSequence then set the endpoint using `MusicSequenceSetMIDIEndpoint`.

Comment: I'm trying to do this, but I'm confused. MIDISend requires an output port and destination. Why does MusicSequenceSetMIDIEndpoint only require a destination? Even though I set the destination to my MIDI interface, nothing plays through the interface.